# My local files are missing

Tags: git

So I went to edit my .htaccess file after trying to push my local git repository to github. This is the first time I've done that and was having some issues but now my .htaccess is gone as well a ton of other files within the /assets directory and I'm freaking out. This is what I did:

1. git add my working directory locally
2. git rm files that I didn't want in my repository
3. git commit
4. attempt to push to github.com with some issues, and tried a few things including a prune
5. noticed that my repository only has one directory and another is missing
6. noticed that my .htaccess file was gone, as well as all the files in the 'assets' directory although the folders are still there.
7. other files I removed from the repository are still there

I don't know what happened, but I checked my Trash, I only have one branch 'Master' and my files are gone. I just want my directory to be back and delete git completely and start over. I'm assuming the current directory is reflecting the branch I'm on.

Comment: If you're running Windows, you could check to see if you have a recent restore point. Not sure what other options you may have, as I'm a Git n00b myself...

Comment: It sounds highly likely that you did not, in fact, add the files from your directory to git and commit. If they stayed untracked, then the `git prune` would have deleted them.

Comment: prune doesn't touch the work tree

Comment: Try `git checkout master`, if that doesn't fix anything try `git checkout master@{1}`, if that doesn't work try `git reflog show HEAD` and see if there's anything before your pull.

Comment: Before doing anything I would suggest that you make a copy of your entire directory (make sure .git is included).

Comment: what do you see when running `git ls-files` ?

Comment: Okay so I think what happened is that I added my whole directory to git, then used git rm which I thought would just prevent the files from being tracked (Git Ignore probably was what I wanted) and that deleted the files. Because this was prior to my first commit, basically I deleted the files permanently, and it doesn't seem that they are in my trash. Hard lesson learned. *DO NOT USE GIT RM BEFORE INITIAL COMMIT* Does this sound right??

Comment: What you would have wanted to use would have been "git rm --cached ..." to only remove the files from the index but not touch the worktree. And after that you would have wanted to add the files to .gitignore.

Comment: git rm should have been very verbose and reluctant to remove the files so destructively. Did you ignore the warnings and force it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not want to delete some files, just tell git not to track them.
For this purpose, "git rm" is a very bad idea indeed. It deletes those from the worktree as well.

Instead you should add the untracked files to a .gitignore file before adding everything to the repo.

```
git init
echo /assets > .gitignore
echo .htaccess >> .gitignore
git add .
git commit
```

As to restoring your files, I've no idea...

Answer (score 0):

please try

```
git checkout master
```

to see if it reverts your file?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that what you did was:

```
git add *
```

Or something along those lines.  That command typically does not include your "dot files". The shell (that might be cmd, bash, zsh, or whatever it is you're using) defines how how that '*' does globbing.

You then did the rest of your work, on the mistaken belief that all your files were added. You didn't check the output of 'git status'.

When you did:

```
git rm file-you-do-not-want
```

You may have either ignored any warnings and tried to ensure that the files were gone.

In any case, the git commit you ended up creating did not include all the files you had.  In future I recommend you check what you have by using:

```
git status
git gui
gitk
```

If, however, the files existed before in git, then you may wish to use:

```
git reflog
```

To show you a list of the previous commits you used to be on before.  Try iteratively checking out those commit sha1's to see if they contain the 'missing' files.